# Must I bind haproxy to port 22 to load balance ssh/sftp

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, load-balancing, haproxy, sftp

I need to use haproxy to load-balance SFTP connections but currently i cannot bind it to port 22 (cutomer constraint). Can i bind to port xxx and listen on port 22 to achieve this or must I bind to 22?

Thanks

Comment: What's the difference between "binding to a port" and "listening to a port"?

Comment: that's my beginners question, apologies if its too simplistic? Perhaps they are synonymous?

Comment: This is the case, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The *bind* and *listen* are not the same things nor things that can be done independently. They are consequent stages on the same port number. It is well described in this diagram from Wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You *can* expose SSH on any port you desire. The clients must be aware of that, however.

```
listen ssh-balanced
    bind <public-ip>:5022
    mode tcp
    server term01 <internal-ip1>:22 check
    server term02 <internal-ip2>:22 check
```

You need to use `ssh -p5022` to connect, and `scp -P5022` etc.

Comment: Hi Felix,  yes, i can get this working, the problem is i cannot instruct clients to use a different port. I am considering using iptables to use a route connections on 22 to an arbitrary port such as 5022, i could use it that way

Comment: You could get away with NAT, but why even bother not binding port 22 then. I disbelieve that such a setup would honor the constraint from your customer.

Comment: my customer must send to port 22 (cannot modify) but my employer does not want me to bind to 22 on our server as haproxy already running here and bound for http load balancing etc

Comment: This is not a haproxy issue whatsoever. If you don't open port 22, it will not be reachable for the customer. It's as simple as that. You might be able to reconcile this conflict of interests using a VPN.